Programatically logged in customer not persistent with magento 2 fpc enabled
i have created a a ajax controller which log in customer programatically after getting the otp from the customer and after getting the response i refresh the page , the problem is when full page caching is enabled it do not work properly and somtime the customer gets logged in and sometime not but if i disable full page caching , it works perfectly .
below is my js and controller code
js code
    jQuery.ajax({
    url:  baseUrl+'employeepopup/index/loginemployee',
    type: "GET",
    data: {email:email,mobile:mobile,emailDomain:emailDomain,isNumberPrefilled:isNumberPrefilled,employeeType:employeeType,otp:otp},
    showLoader: true,
    cache:false,
    success:function(response){
        if(response == 'true'){
            location.reload();
        }
        else{
            $('body').trigger('processStop');
            $('.employee-error-msg').text('Incorrect OTP');
            $('.employee-error-msg').show();
        }
    }
});

and in the controller i have
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class LoginEmployee extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

public function __construct(
  Context $context,
  Session $customerSession,

) {
  $this->session = $customerSession;
  parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{

    $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/loogin.log');
    $logger = new \Zend_Log();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);


    $customerData = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');
    $customer = $customerData->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("mobilenumber", $mobile)->getFirstItem();
    $this->session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
    $this->session->regenerateId();
    $sessionid = $this->session->getSessionId();
    $logger->info("newly generate session id is " .$sessionid);
    $return = 'true';    
    
    $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
    $logger->info("$return");
    $resultJson->setData($return);
    return $resultJson;
}
}


We can’t get any data from customer session when a cache is enabled Because as soon as layout generation started, customer session will be cleared by \Magento\PageCache\Model\Layout\DepersonalizePlugin::afterGenerateXml on all cacheable pages. So we can’t get any customer session data from \Magento\Customer\Model\Session.
using httpContext we can get a customer is logged in or not. In httpContext only customer_group and customer_not_logged_in are defined. So Customer id, Name, Email and other customer attributes are not defined in httpContext.
So we will create a plugin to set customer session data in httpContext
Create di.xml file in app/code/[vendor]/[ModuleName]/etc/frontend
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction">
        <plugin name="customer-session-data-to-context" type="[vendor]\[ModuleName]\Plugin\SessionContext" sortOrder="15"/>
    </type>
</config>

Create SessionContext.php file in app/code/[vendor]/[ModuleName]/Plugin
<?php
namespace [vendor]\[ModuleName]\Plugin;

class SessionContext
{
    /**
    * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
    */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
    */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
    * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    }

    /**
    * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface $subject
    * @param callable $proceed
    * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function aroundDispatch(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->httpContext->setValue(
            'customer_id',
            $this->customerSession->getCustomerId(),
            false
        );

        $this->httpContext->setValue(
            'customer_name',
            $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getName(),
            false
        );

        $this->httpContext->setValue(
            'customer_email',
            $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail(),
            false
        );

        return $proceed($request);
    }
}

Now if you want to get customer session data you can use httpContext like below, I have used in block
<?php

namespace [vendor]\[ModuleName]\Block;

class VendorLogin extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $httpContext;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCustomerIsLoggedIn()
    {
        return (bool)$this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
    }

    public function getCustomerId()
    {
        return $this->httpContext->getValue('customer_id');
    }

    public function getCustomerName()
    {
        return $this->httpContext->getValue('customer_name');
    }

    public function getCustomerEmail()
    {
        return $this->httpContext->getValue('customer_email');
    }

}


nikhil i want to programatically login the customer , my issue is not related to get customer data .. setCustomerAsLoggedIn is not logging the customer , the phpsessid is generated when i check the log but old phpsessionid is found in the browser cookie variable
